# Inserting HTML in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, contenteditable

I try to make a rich text editor using a content editable UIWebView, as UITextView doesn't get any enrichment. I wonder how I can replace a selection programmatically or insert HTML code (for example to create a link to the selected text, or to implement a search/replace function). I tried:

```
[self.webTexteView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.ExecCommand('insertHTML', false, '%@')", myString]];
```

but it doesn't work... Do you know if there is a solution to that?

Thanks,

Denis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is late, but just incase anyone else is looking at this your original solution works, you just accidentally have

```
document.ExecCommand
```

it should be

```
document.execCommand
```

Ive tested it with the lower case e and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can load html into your webview using the `loadHTMLString:` message. I expect that is not what you want.

After loading some html you have two options for communicating between the javascript in your webview and you objective-c code. 1 is initiated from objective-c and 2 is initiated from javascript.

1. You can execute execute javascript using the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` message on your uiwebview. This is quite flexible, and can be used both to inject code, and to call existing code. E.g. you could do `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"editor\").innerHTML"]` to get the content from a div with id editor.
2. By implementing the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you can be notified, through `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` every time a url is requested opened in the webview. This gives you a chance to extract information from the url, and cancel any further loading by returning `NO`. E.g. In you javascript you could do `document.location = "bold";` when the cursor passes over some bold text. This would give you a chance to update your ui to reflect this.

Comment: This is the first option I use, with 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:' , and it works perfectly to make the selection bold or italic. I would be happy not to be obliged to use loadHTMLString... since I would loose the selection and would be obliged to make a find/replace without knowing the range...

Comment: I cannot vote, since I'm a newbie on this website... still not found solution to this problem... NSText was a great solution on OSX, probably initiated to lower the MS Word domination on Macintosh. On iOS, no Microsoft, no effort by Apple... that helps this company to sell their "Pages" application which is definitely not a solution for most text-hungry people...